# Batch script; looking to strip newline tokens from a copy-pasted user input as the input is fed to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have the following .bat script (with some specifics hidden to hide sensitive info); the intent is for the user to run the script and be able to paste in a set of account IDs (generally from an Excel doc), which are then processed into URLs to open a set of tabs in new browser tabs. I've chosen to try do this as a .bat to minimise the overhead needed for users (only one file I have to give them to run with nothing needed to be installed, copy-paste values in, tada! the accounts open in browser).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Test script - opens multiple accounts in new browser tabs.
set /p input= Enter account IDs:

set n=0
for %%a in (%input%) do (
    set /A n+=1
    set "accountID[!n!]=%%~a"
)


for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
    echo %%i- !accountID[%%i]!
    start "" chrome.exe "hidden"!accountID[%%i]!"hidden"
)
pause
```

This works perfectly as expected if the IDs are typed manually with spaces as separators; however, if the IDs are pasted from Excel, only the first is processed, due to the linebreaks (\r\n) that are introduced after each ID due to the IDs being copied from a column in Excel.

Is there a way around this/something I can do to strip out or ignore the linebreaks as the data is being passed in?

I've looked over several existing questions here and on other sites; as far as I can tell none of them are trying to do exactly this, but I may very well have missed some due to insufficient google-fu. Any pointers or assistance would be appreciated.

As far as I can tell this would be simple using a separate input file to read from, however I'm trying to minimise the total steps needed for the user (opening a separate file, pasting the data in, saving the file, running script etc).

I've considered using the translate function (to try changing \n to ' ' for example), but from what I can tell that doesn't appear to be doable while assigning the variable; only once it's assigned, which is past when the issue I'm encountering occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[untested]

```
set n=0

:again
set "input="
set /p input= Enter account IDs:
if not defined input goto alldone

for %%a in (%input%) do (
    set /A n+=1
    set "accountID[!n!]=%%~a"
)
goto again

:alldone
```

I don't have the facility to test this at the moment.

The issue is - what to do to indicate to the batch that the input is finished.

So - first set the count to `0`.

Then repeatedly `set` the value of `input` to *nothing*. read the input and if it's *nothing*, skip over the accumulation of numbers

Note that if just <kbd>Enter</kbd> is "pressed" then the value of the variable is **not changed** by `set /p`.

Hence, clear `input`, then ask for a new value.

Note that it will be necessary to include the next line (an empty cell) as the input pasted.

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you.
Empty cell/value at the end and a single enter press proceeds to open the tabs, but two enter presses also seems to work just fine.